# Android How to show alert on another app

Tags: java, android, alert, android-notifications

Hi I want to show alert after click on my notification. Here is code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_stat, "Powiadomionko", System.currentTimeMillis());

 notification.ledARGB = Color.CYAN;//0xFFff0000;
 notification.ledOnMS = 800; 
 notification.ledOffMS = 2400;

 notification.vibrate = new long[]{100, 120, 100, 120};

 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TerminarzActivity.class);

 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 notification.setLatestEventInfo(Serwis_updateTERM.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
 notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

And I want to show Alert on anything not on my Activity after click. Anyone know how to do this ?

I know i must add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

but nothing else..

Comment: You mean you want your application to show the alert dialog no matter what? You could try creating a broadcast receiver that receives an intent passed by your application when you want the notification to show. In receiving that broadcast you could pop your alert. Not sure if it would work, but sounds logical

Answer (score 1):

Check out the creation of this notification (taken from `Geofence` sample). This code creates a notification and if you touch it it launches your MainActivity.

```
    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    // Construct a task stack
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions
    // >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Set the notification contents
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_title, transitionType, ids))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

This code might help you, but still it depends what do you mean by "alert".